# How to get the PeekPokeTester expect function to print signal values in hex?

Tags: chisel

By default when I call the expect() function in the tester the values come up as decimals. Although in the provided example here:
https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel-testers/wiki/Using-the-PeekPokeTester
the outputs comes out as hex. How can you select this?

example:

`[info] [0.026] EXPECT AT 5   io_key_column got 979262996 expected 4293125357 FAIL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `Driver.execute` to run your test. It allows you to set a bunch of options by passing in an array of strings.
In this case try

```
val args = Array("--display-base", "16")
iotesters.Driver.execute(args, () => new RealGCD2) { c =>
  new GCDPeekPokeTester(c)
} should be (true)
```